# How can I use purrr with str_split

Tags: r, stringr, purrr

Still trying to get to grips with purrr

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(text=c("Even Flow", "My Sweet Lord"))
```

How can I use, presumably,  map_chr and str_split to get, say, a vector of the second text elements i.e "Flow" "Sweet"

TIA

Comment: I think you want to use purrr:map() to define a function to iterate over the column in your df.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(text=c("Even Flow", "My Sweet Lord"))
df[, text_second := tstrsplit(text, " ")[2]]
```

and using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
df$text %>% map(str_split, pattern = " ") %>% map_chr(c(1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks for alternative solutions and speed of response